# How to embed bokeh js output figure inside a div element?

Tags: javascript, bokeh, bokehjs

I have following HTML and JS code(pasted below) to create Bokeh-JS pie chart. But its not giving expected result. Bokeh plots are not getting embedded inside div elements of HTML code.

Am I missing something here? Also I've attached output of the code.

HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.13.min.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.13.min.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-0.12.13.min.css">
    <style>
    .floating-box {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 150px;
        height: 75px;
        margin: 10px;
        border: 3px solid #73AD21;  
    }

    </style>

    <title></title>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="container">
    <div id="button">
                <button id="pie_report" type='button' value="Pie Report"
                    name="Pie Report" class="button button1" onClick="execute()">Pie_Report</button>
    </div>

    <div id="bokeh_ch1" class="floating-box"> 
    </div>              

    <div id="bokeh_ch2" class="floating-box"> 
    </div>      
    </div>              

</body>
<script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.13.min.js"></script>         
<script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.13.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-0.12.13.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-api-0.12.13.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="my_js.js"></script>

</html>
```

my_js.js file code:

```
function execute(){ 

    var plt =  Bokeh.Plotting;

    var pie_data = {
        labels: ['Work', 'Eat', 'Commute', 'Sport', 'Watch TV', 'Sleep'],
        values: [8, 2, 2, 4, 0, 8],
    };

    var inc_sr={labels:['incident','Sr'],
        values: [53,65]

    };
     var p0 = Bokeh.Charts.pie(inc_sr,{palette:['#FF8C00'   ,'#A0522D'],
        inner_radius: 0.0,width:20,height:20,
        start_angle: Math.PI / 2,
        end_angle: 5 * Math.PI / 2
    });
    var p1 = Bokeh.Charts.pie(pie_data);


        document.getElementById('bokeh_ch1').innerHTML=plt.show(p0); 
    document.getElementById('bokeh_ch2').innerHTML=plt.show(p1);
}
```

[Attaching output of this code when I hit Pie_Report button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKdob.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `Bokeh.Plotting.show` accepts two arguments, the first being a (chart?) `obj` and the second being a `target`.  Calling `plt.show(p0)` with one argument simply appends the chart to the body and assigns the returned object to the `innerHTML` of the div. Instead, give it the `Id` of the element you want the chart to be inserted into:

```
plt.show(p0, '#bokeh_ch1')
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vxevupLn/9/)

You can also pass in a `HTML element` or a `jQuery` object as the second argument as seen in the `show` function from the [bokeh-api source code](http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-api-0.12.13.js) (line 6494): (I removed code and added my comments)

```
exports.show = function (obj, target) {
    // variable declaration
    if (target == null) { // no target specified, set element to body
        element = document.body;
    } else if (types_1.isString(target)) { // assume selector passed in
        element = document.querySelector(target); // find element in page
        if (element == null) { // element not found in page
            throw new Error('\'' + target + '\' selector didn\'t match any elements');
        }
    } else if (target instanceof HTMLElement) { // if an HTML element is passed,
        element = target; // use that element
    } else if (typeof $ !== 'undefined' && $ !== null && target instanceof $) {
        element = target[0]; // target is a jQuery object, get the HTML element
    } else {
        throw new Error('target should be HTMLElement, string selector, $ or null');
    }
    // append element
};
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how did you get to know plt.show() will accept two arguments? Any documentation link please?

Comment: No, sorry I couldn't find any documentation.  I set a breakpoint on the line calling `plt.show` and entered in the console `plt.show` which returns the function params/body: `ƒ (t,e){var r,s,l,u,c,h,p;if(h=a.isArray(t),l=new i,h)`... and I saw it took `t`, which I assumed was the chart, and `e` which I assumed was an `element`, so I started by just giving it `bokeh_ch1` which didn't work, then realized it was probably a `selector` and gave it `#bokeh_ch1` which worked.

Comment: Great debug. Thanks.

Comment: I've posted the source code and my attempt at an explanation.  You can use those javascript script links and change the `.min.js` extension to just `.js` for a non-minified version that is easier to debug with.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks alot :)